# How to create a truth table based on table of values in r

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, truthtable

I am trying to create a script that will create a truth table based on different values.

Example

[image: First table]

The truth table for this would be

[image: Truth table version of above table]

I'm fairly new to r. I know it has a lot of great capabilities when it comes to data analysis, but this would help a lot. Was looking at potentially implementing something with sparse matrices, but I don't know.

Comment: take a look at `model.matrix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, please include data in your question, and avoid putting images.

May be this using `data.table`:

**Data:**

```
library('data.table')
df1 <- data.table(Name = c('Bob', 'Bob', 'Luke'),
                  Location = c('Texas', 'Ohio', 'Utah'),
                  Pet = c('Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog'),
                  Coder = c(1,0,1),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

**Code:**

```
df1[, id := .I ] # assign unique id, and later it will be removed
select_cols <- c('Name', 'Location', 'Pet') # selected columns
dcast( data = melt(df1, measure.vars = select_cols ),  
       formula = "id + Coder ~ value", 
       fun.aggregate = length, 
       fill = 0  )[, id := NULL ][]

#    Coder Bob Cat Dog Luke Ohio Texas Utah
# 1:     1   1   0   1    0    0     1    0
# 2:     0   1   1   0    0    1     0    0
# 3:     1   0   0   1    1    0     0    1
```